# Is a 'Protagonist' really a thing or is it a misnomer derived from it's opposite 'Antagonist'?

Tags: origin-unknown

I ask because in anatomy and fitness the muscle groups can defined in three categories for a given workout: `Agonist` (the main muscle being worked), `Antagonist` (the muscle group that would work the opposing direction (think bicep/tricep)), and `assisters` (stabilizing muscles that are being worked, but not primarily so).

Does it not stand to reason that this naming would follow this metaphor into literature where the `Agonist` is the character who we are to agonize along with as they struggle, and the `Antagonist` is the character who works directly against that struggle?

My suspicion is that at some point someone determined that the opposite of `Antagonist` should be the `Protagonist` and the naming just sort of stuck.  What is a `tagonist` anyway? and how do I know if I am `Pro` or `An..?` amiright?  Of course I could be dead wrong and someone else can tell me that the roots of these words are not at all what I think they are.

Anyone..? Anyone..? Bueller..?

Comment: Why downvote?  If I have tagged this wrong or if it is a duplicate please let me know; but the question itself is valid, well articulated, and well thought out.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Your premise is incorrect: it comes directly from the [Greek _protagonistes_](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=protagonist)

Comment: I did not DV, but I suspect that someone found the lack of basic research to be problematic.

Comment: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/protagonist

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Comment: https://www.etymonline.com/word/protagonist

Comment: There does appear to be some merit to what I am saying here though as Protagonist and Antagonist are portrayed as opposites, yet do not share the same roots: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/antagonist Protagonist = first in importance + actor while Antagonist = struggle against.  One would intuitively have expected some form of last in importance + actor.

Comment: They both come from the Greek. See [Antagonist on etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=antagonist)  as well as  [Protagonist](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=protagonist) on the same site.   So saying that they developed into opposites in English probably has little merit.

Comment: I think are mistaking the Greek _protos_ for Latin _pro_. It ain't the same thing.

Comment: The calls for research seem harsh, but finding the Greek origins of _proto(s)-_ and _ant(i)_ doesn't seem to take a lot of effort. Asking what a "tagonist" is shows you didn't put in even that effort.

Comment: As an alternative question, I would look for evidence for relating the naming of muscle groups and the labeling of characters. Was it anatomists like Andreas Vesalius and others that first applied these labels to muscles? Were they drawn to Greek or Latin literary language, or more broadly to basic meanings?

Comment: @oerkelens Looking that up and finding out that _tagonist_ is nothing is precisely the research being called for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to do something I normally would never do: answer a question which I believe should be closed for lack of research. I am doing this  mainly because Greek and Latin roots and prefixes  are often confused, and this should be clarified.

In this case, ["protagonist" comes from the Greek *protagoniste*](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=protagonist)...

> 1670s, "principal character in a story, drama, etc.," from ***Greek protagonistes*** "actor who plays the chief or first part,"

["Antagonist" comes from the Greek *antagoniste*](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=antagonist)

> "one who contends with another," 1590s, from French antagoniste (16c.) or directly from Late Latin antagonista,  ***from Greek antagonistes*** "

Many people confuse the Greek and Latin prefixes.

In this case, the prefix is from the Greek *protos*, not the Latin *pro*. Also, there can be confusion between the Greek *anti*, and the Latin *contra*, which usually appears as the prefix "con" in English.

Source: [etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/)

Comment: In hindsight I could have researched this more, since the overarching question is easily answered, as you did here.  I would be lying if I said I am satisfied though... Language is a fickle thing and this case still smells a bit off for me.  From what I can gather disparate words were picked from different roots,  the differences were formatted out till they appear almost exactly the same in English, and then were used in context as exact opposites.  There is a lot of wiggle room for how that unfortunate scenario came about, but one should definitely not rule out human error.

Comment: As a part of my personal policy, I up-ticked your Q because I presented an answer.

Comment: " From what I can gather disparate words were picked from different roots, the differences were formatted out till they appear almost exactly the same in English, and then were used in context as exact opposites." Welcome to _language_. Please let go of the idea there are people defining a language somewhere in an office. Language _happens_ and it doesn't always make sense. Hey, English is a Germanic language, and yet here we are discussing Latin... Observation is great, but _DO NOT_ think there are "rules" in any real language :)